# How to check one type conforms to another/typehint

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I want to have a way of making sure a type conforms to the type hint, for example:

```
check_type(str, str) -> True
check_type(str, typing.Union(str, int)) -> True
check_type(typing.List[str], typing.List(typing.Any)) -> True
```

I see Mypy has `is_subtype` but doesn't look to accept typing instance/raw types, but rather a proprietary `Type` instance?

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no responses and I required this functionality for another task, I built my own little module.

This is *not* an exhaustive solution, but works for the cases I am likely to come across. I will keep adding as required!

https://pypi.org/project/valid-typing